# Downloading image from web takes too much of time in Listview

Tags: android

Hi in my application i need to download some images and text from the web and need to display in listview. for that i'm using POJO class means initially storing all the images in to the POJO class and then display in listview

It is good for less images but while downloading more than 100+ plus images it taking too much of time to load,

can anybody suggest some good solution for this.

Comment: Get a faster internet speed?

Comment: you first download image then show or while showing list download image?

Comment: Hi may i know whats wrong in my question ?

Comment: @Shayanpourvatan right now i downloaded the image first and showing in listview but it taking more time,i need some alternate way to reduce the time

Comment: you can use AsyncTask class to do your job parallel, while showing list all image downloaded, then first time that you run maybe not see any image but in continue all image loaded.

Comment: @Eyes see https://github.com/thest1/LazyList this is great simple for what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following libraries which are able to do lazy loading :

1. [UrlImageViewHelper](https://github.com/koush/UrlImageViewHelper)
2. [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)
3. [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso)

All these libraries are `lazy loading` ready which means these libraries can reuses views in widgets like `ListView` and `GridView`.

Comment: Thank you i'm expecting like this only,can u provide me some sample code

Comment: Just visit their GitHub page add their .jar lib to your project and you will be able to use them. Download their sample projects they have all the code you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use AsyncTask() method.Since it is doing its process in background it may work quicker.

Comment: i'm doing that in AsyncTask() only

Comment: @Eyes you use `AsyncTask` for internet connection but we say use `AsynkTask` in `getView()` method not in main class and before showing list

Comment: @Eyes see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview